# SQL using variable in where clause before equal

Tags: sql, variables, sql-server-2000, declare

I'm trying to write a simple SQL query to resolve some prices from an some older SQL Server 2000. The problem is we have 6 different prices and I would to make it so that I only have to change one caretaker to get this done.

I declared a variable as char at the top and tried to get those char down into the statement. This is working half, for the part after the equal. The code here at the bottom is working. But I need to change the "dbo.dep_art.VB05". The 5 in VB05 must equal the @ID. So when I change the the @ID into 4 the VB05 must be VB04. I tried dbo.dep_art.VB0@ID and dbo.dep_art.VB0&@ID, but that didn't worked. Also tried a second Variable as nvarchar and set it as dbo.dep_art.VB05, but that also went wrong.

Please remember: it is a SQL Server 2000.

```
Declare @ID as char
set @ID = 5

/*.................*/

select distinct(dbo.dep_prs.ARTNR), 
    dbo.dep_art.Bezeichnung, 
    dbo.dep_prs.PR_Brutto 
from 
    dep_prs, dep_art 
where 
    dbo.dep_prs.ARTNR = dbo.dep_art.ARTNR 
    and dbo.dep_prs.Preisgruppe = 1 
    and dbo.dep_art.VB05 = 2 
    and dbo.dep_prs.LIdx = @ID 
     or dbo.dep_prs.ARTNR = dbo.dep_art.ARTNR 
    and dbo.dep_prs.Preisgruppe = 1 
    and dbo.dep_art.VB05 = 3 
    and dbo.dep_prs.LIdx = @ID
order by 
    dbo.dep_prs.artnr
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also: If you define a variable as `char` *without* specifying a length - then you get a variable of **exactly 1 character** length - is that what you want / need ?? If not: use `varchar(n)` to define a string variable that can be up to `n` characters long! Furthermore: if you define a variable as `char` and you want to assign something to it - use **single quotes** to denote the string value: `set @ID = '5'`. Without the single quotes, it's an **integer** value, and SQL Server will have to do a conversion

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Bad habits indeed, only used join as a Left Join in some query's, never uses join in this kind of query. I'll try to improve. As for the char, I only need one character  ( 1 to 6 ). Also bad habits from the time that 640k was enough for everyone. And I forgot the single quotes, I noticed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 6 options and it won't develop farther:
you can use if ... else

I don't suggest to use dynamic sql in 2000 version